# Matrix multiplication with dot products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was wondering about trying to factor the following expression, but I couldn't come up with anything.
$$ (A{\bf v}) \cdot (A{\bf{w}})
$$
We can't factor out the matrix $A$ because we cannot multiply a matrix with the result of a dot product as it is a scalar. Surely there is something I am missing, is there any other useful expression we can form that is equal to this?

Comment: Write v' = Av and w' = Aw, and note that v' dot w' can be writeen as v'^T w'

Comment: Ahh okay thank you so much friend! this helped a lot. I am working with rotational matrices and this works: (Rv)^T Rw = v^T R^T R w, since R is rotational, the transpose is also the inverse, so this simplifies to v^T w = v dot w.

Comment: We may as well evaluate the generalization$$(Av)\cdot(Bw)=(Av)_i(Bw)_i=v_jA_{ij}B_{ik}w_k=v_j(A^TBw)_j=v\cdot A^TBw$$with [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benjamin_Gal's comment answered but I am putting this to close the question.

> Write $v' = Av$ and $w' = Aw$, and note that $v' \cdot w'$ can be written as $v'^T w'$. 
> -[Benjamin_Gal's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4446332/matrix-multiplication-with-dot-products#comment9310570_4446332)

Comment: I edited to put the comment in your answer because comments can be removed

Comment: ahh okay thanks for the help, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "useful expression" as you ask for one.

Transform the dot product in this way:

$$Av.Aw=(Av)^TAw=v^TA^TAw=v^T(A^TA)w$$

Matrix $G=A^TA$ is called the ["Gram matrix"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) associated with $A$.

Its generic entry $$G_{ij}=C_i \ . \ C_j$$

is the dot product of column $i$ with column $j$ of the initial matrix $A$.